# How do I dynamically create charts using one javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, apexcharts

I am using Apex Charts to visualize my data. I've been experimenting and although creating one function per chart seems great, I'd like to automize this. I haven't found any documentation so far that explains how you can seamlessly create multiple charts using only one function. I keep running into errors like `Element not found` even though I've already generated `<div id="chart1"></div> <div id="chart1"></div> <div id="chart1"></div>` in my HTML doc.

I'm thinking that there's sort of a conflict with the ids.

My javascript code (here I want to dynamically create 3 doughnut charts for the three elements in the list - so that if the list changes and has 10, 20, n elements, charts are automatically generated):

```
const list = [1, 4, 5];
    // Example datasets and labels
    const dataset1 = [30, 50, 20]; // Example dataset 1
    const labels1 = ["Label A", "Label B", "Label C"]; // Labels for dataset 1

    const dataset2 = [40, 30, 30]; // Example dataset 2
    const labels2 = ["Label X", "Label Y", "Label Z"]; // Labels for dataset 2

    const dataset3 = [10, 70, 20]; // Example dataset 3
    const labels3 = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]; // Labels for dataset 3


    function createContainer(list){
        const container = document.querySelector("#container");
        for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){      
            const value = list[i];   
            const chartContent = document.createElement("div");
            chartContent.id = `chart${value}`;

           container.appendChild(chartContent);
           console.log(chartContent);
           generateChart(i);
        }
    }

    function generateChart(value){
        if(value == 1){
            renderDoughnutChart(dataset1, labels1, `chart${value}`);
        } else if (value == 4){
            renderDoughnutChart(dataset2, labels2, `chart${value}`);
        } else {
            renderDoughnutChart(dataset3, labels3, `chart${value}`);
        }
        
    }

    // Function to generate and render a doughnut chart using ApexCharts
    function renderDoughnutChart(dataset, labels, containerId) {
        const options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'donut',
                toolbar: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            series: dataset,
            labels: labels,
        };

        const chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById(containerId), options);
        chart.render();
    }

    createContainer(list);
```

How do I correct and manage this?

Comment: IDs (as the abbreviation implies) must be unique.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This does not help. How do I change the code?

Comment: You probably wanted to call `generateChart(value);` not `generateChart(i);`